# Find the image of the line $Y=5X+7$ under the collineation $\alpha(x,y)=(-x,y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Find the image of the line $Y=5X+7$ under the collineation $\alpha(x,y)=(-x,y)$

I dont understand how to find image of a line under a collineation

Can someone kindly help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put X as -x and y as y

You have to just replace X and y in the equation with (-x,y)

It becomes y=5(-x)+7

Y=-5x +7

Answer (score 1):

On the original line, there are points such as $(-1,2)$ and $(2,17)$, so by applying $\alpha$ (just a sign change on the $x$-coordinate) to these points, the image line should contain $(1,2)$ and $(-2,17)$. Knowing that the result is a line, you could infer its equation from two points such as these, but you can also directly apply $\alpha$ to the generic point $(x,5x+7)$, arriving at $(-x,5x+7)$. To bring that into a more useful form, substitute $x$ with $-x$ to arrive at $(-(-x),5(-x)+7)=(x,-5x+7)$ and conclude that the image line is given by $y=-5x+7$.